# App crashes ,When i click button i made for increment or decrement of quantity

Tags: java, android, runtime-error, fatal-error

I'm following the instructions from the official android site to
create my first android app.  Problem - When I click the button to
"increase or decrease" a quantity, the app crashes.

logcat

```
W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000001
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.yash.myapplication, PID: 29603
              java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5207)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21168)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
               Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5207) 
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21168) 
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 
               Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
                  at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:312)
                  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4427)
                  at com.example.yash.myapplication.MainActivity.display(MainActivity.java:57)
                  at com.example.yash.myapplication.MainActivity.IncrementQuantity(MainActivity.java:21)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5207) 
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21168) 
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 29603 SIG: 9
```

can any one say why this is happening???

Comment: MainActivity.java     `package com.example.yash.myapplication;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int quantity=0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

Comment: public void IncrementQuantity(View view) {
    quantity=quantity+1;
        display(quantity);
    }

    public void DecrementQuantity(View view) {
    quantity=quantity-1;
        display(quantity);
    }

Comment: Put the Source Code in your question so one can **read** it.

Comment: @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    public void submitOrder(View view) {
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.whippedcreamcheckbox);
        boolean haschecked = checkBox.isChecked();

        int price = quantity * 10;
        String ordermessage= CreateOrdersummary(price,haschecked);
        displayordersummary(ordermessage);
        //  addListenerOnButton();


    }
        public void display(int number) {
        TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.quantity_textView);
        textView.setText(number);
    }

Comment: Don't put code in comments, edit your question instead. `Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1`. You tried to access a resource which did not exist.

Comment: here it is the MainActivity.java   in the above comment of mine

Comment: Try accessing a resource that _does_ exist?

Comment: **sorry guyz im not able to add my code ...its giving error of It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details..and i m eager to solve this so alternative solution i posted code in comments**

Comment: Or you could add some more details like the error message says. Per site policy and for readability please put the code in the question itself.

Comment: Also, please don't use the [android-studio] tag for general programming questions.

Answer (score 0):

You tried to access a resource using an id that doesn't exist or wasn't typed properly.

Inside of your display function :

> Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String
>   resource ID #0x1
>                     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:312)
>                     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4427)
>                     at com.example.yash.myapplication.MainActivity.display(MainActivity.java:57)
>                     at com.example.yash.myapplication.MainActivity.IncrementQuantity(MainActivity.java:21)

You likely used the wrong id when you created the handle to your TextView.
`TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.quantity_textView);`

Make sure that `quantity_textView` exists. If you know that that id is correct, make sure that in your layout file you've used `android:id="@+id/quantity_textView"`

**Please make sure you copy your code into your question to make it readable.**

Comment: **at android.widget.TextView.setText**... The findViewById is not the problem

Comment: haha yes you're right. My answer is moot

Comment: Now it's too late to add the correct answer, I guess! Whoops

Comment: You can [edit] your existing answer

Comment: Thank you Taylor for your response , although i understood my problem with the help of solution posted by cricket_007.

Comment: i am new to stackover flow and learning android and your votes is motivating me to ask more doubt ill occur during my learning period also next time ill take care of the format of question to post..

Comment: Ya, it was just that you passed in an int instead of a string. Android uses int as its id's so it thought you were trying to look for an id. I realized how silly it was when cricket replied to me.